# Given that $1<a<2$ and $1<b<2$ .What is the most accurate framing of the number $f(x)=\frac{a+b}{2a+b}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given that $1<a<2$ and $1<b<2$

I have to find the value of $x$ and $y$ such that $y-x=0.15$ for $x<\frac{a+b}{2a+b}<y$

$\frac{1}{8}<\frac{1}{2a+b}<\frac{1}{3}$ and $2<a+b<4$ so $\frac{1}{4}<\frac{a+b}{2a+b}<\frac{4}{3}$

but $\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{12}=0.416667$

we see that $0.416667>0.15$

so I need to use another form of $f(x)=\frac{a+b}{2a+b}$

I heared about reduced form of $\frac{ax+b}{bx+c}$ I think I have to use it but I don't know how to do ... .Can somone help me ?

Comment: The use of the same symbol $x$ here for a lower bound of the expression $(a + b)/(2a + b)$, *and* in the expression "$f(x)$" (where a value for "$x$" has not been defined) is unfortunate - and in my answer, I may not have helped matters, by presuming on your behalf to give, retrospectively, a value to the "$x$" in your "$f(x$)"! Sorry about that. (And welcome to MathSE, by the way - I'm quite new here myself - I hope this hasn't been too bumpy a ride so far!)

Comment: Im also new. and english is not my mother language I can't understand all things but I can know what is meaning . one thing is that i didnt understand what are u meaning by express the fraction as a function of the single quantity x=b/a ?

Comment: I meant: divide both the numerator and denominator by $a$ (which we know is not zero, so division is OK).

Comment: See my answer for the R-rated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitorizing
Calum Gilhooley's answer
(and possibly annoying some people):

$\begin{array}\\
r
&=\frac{a+b}{2a+b}\\
&=\frac{2a+b-a}{2a+b}\\
&=1-\frac{a}{2a+b}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2+b/a}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2+x} 
\quad (x = b/a, 1/2 < x < 2)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$1-\frac14 
> r 
> 1-\frac1{5/2}
$
or
$\frac35 < r < \frac34
$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Express the fraction as a function of the single quantity $x = b/a$, which varies between $1/2$ and $2$.  Then, rewrite this fractional expression $f(x)$ as an expression in which $x$ appears only once, so that you can more easily derive the maximum and minimum values of $f(x)$ from the known maximum and minimum values of $x$.  These two bounds for $f(x)$ differ by $3/20$, as required.